# Clear the Backstack within an activity without using FLAG

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to clear the back stack within an Activity but not by `startActivity()` and using FLAG. e.g. when I launch an application from the application icon then the application main activity starts but there is some thing in the back stack like the launcher activity because when we touch the minimized app tab the launcher is visible . I want to remove the launcher application from the minimized applications.

Comment: What "launcher" are you talking about? Is this another activity of your application?

Comment: when some one start application from its icon. then there is some thing in the back stack ( minimized app ) that is the launcher.

Comment: No. Only your application's activities are in the back stack. Please be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@SorryForMyEnglish's answer is right. You just cannot to implement it. By using `android:noHistory="boolean"` attribute, see my concept maps below:

[image: concept]

Because of `ActivityC` and `ActivityD` (last activities) has a `true` value, so they cannot back to `MainActivity`, but they can back to `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`. Also, `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` can back to `MainActivity`. And the backstack is completely cleared without using this `startActivity(intent)` to open your next `Activity` (so you will need `FLAG`):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivityToBeOpened.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

After you declared the value in manifest, you just need to call this `startActivity(intent)` to open the next `Activity` (no `FLAG` is needed):

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivityToBeOpened.class));
```

Is it very simple, right?

**Remember:**

- Set your last `Activity` with `android:noHistory="true"` in manifest.
- Another `Activity` must be set with `false` value.
- Apply this attribute for all of your `Activity`.

As additional, here is how to use it inside your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:noHistory="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use `android:noHistory="true"` attribute in Manifest for your Activity

```
<activity android:name="StartActivity"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: this did not worked when I launch my application the launcher is in the minimized application ( back stack )