# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK still bundles activities in the same task

Tags: java, android, android-intent, taskstackbuilder

I have a starting\home activity that is first launched.

In another flow I wrote a broadcast receiver that is triggered by the dialer.

The later shows an transparent activity with popup-fragment on it.

```
    @Override
    protected void handleReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
..
                Intent i = new Intent(context, PopupActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(Constants.DIALED_PHONE, phoneDal.getItem(phoneNumber));
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
                setResultData(null);
```

and yet the popup appear with the transparent hosting activity

but also the "home\main\launch" activity that was opened before hand.

Also when I hide the popup (pressing "home" button)

I see all my app activities are gathered to on task, and not two as I expected.
why is that?

wasn't `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` supposed to solve this?

Comment: Read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27795433/3922207. It's a new idea and simple to use without using `FLAG`.

Comment: @AlbertNicko why to avoid flag? what is missing in my solution?

Comment: You must clear the backstack for your last activities. It may solve your problem (see concept map on my answer). If `PopupActivity.class` is a last activity, set `android:noHistory="true"` inside `<activity />` element in your manifest. I have faced this problem before when using `FLAG` and make my own research to solve this without `FLAG`. And evidently works for me. Until now, I still use my method.