# Why App after crash lands on some activity and does not exit

Tags: android

I have noticed this dual behavior of app crash in different applications. Sometimes on crashing it simply exits the app but other times it lands on some previous activity. Is this a known behavior or is there any logic behind this which can be handled. Tried to search it on SO but couldn't find right combination of keywords for my problem.
Thanks

Comment: maybe the logcat output could be helpfull

Comment: It would be helpful to leave a comment while down voting.

Comment: I think You get downvoted because it´s a too vague question without any code examples or stacktrace. It´s unclear what You mean by "lands on previous activity". If You have no code to share, tell us exactly at which point this happen. For example, start app-->do some stuff-->app crash because...-->etc...

Comment: ohh..I tried to ask it as a generic question which is not related to specific application or code because I have seen this in multiple application.

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: ah, ok. I think the most important  thing is to prevent any crash. I have not seen a behaviour like this. What I think is, If You start Activity A, make a button click and get forwarded to Activity B, Activity A is in the background and not finished. If then Activity B gets crashed, Activity A still exists.

Comment: Try to clear the backstacks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27795433/3922207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the [FLAGS](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) you created the Intent with. For example,  with [CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) If the activity being started is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it are destroyed and this intent is delivered to the resumed instance of the activity (now on top), through onNewIntent()).

When an Activity crashes if there are no more back-stacked activities of the same app, it will simply exit and show the device's home.