# Handling Android back stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a application which have, let say, Activities A, B & C. B can be started by A as well as any other application's activity also. But C can only be started by B. On pressing back on C, user navigates to B(that is ok) but i have a button on C, which on pressing user should navigate to A or any other application's activity which launched B.

Comment: It may helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27795433/3922207

Comment: You want to be able to navigate from `C` back to the Activity that started `B`?

Comment: @AlbertNicko: solution mentioned in the link says to clear back history & hence clearing the activity A which launched B. But i want to go back to A on button click.

Comment: @DavidWasser: yes.. i want to navigate back to activity that started B, with stack clearing entries of B & C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear `B` off the stack and return to the previous Activity, do the following:

in `C`, launch `B` with an EXTRA:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("finish", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Using CLEAR_TOP and SINGLE_TOP here ensure that this will go back to the existing instance of `B`, and not create a new one.

In `B`, override `onNewIntent()` as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra("finished")) {
        // Wants to finish this Activity to return to the previous one
        finish();
    }
}
```

NOTE: This only works if `B` is still in the Activity stack when it launches `C` (ie: it doesn't call `finish()` when launching `C`).

---

An alternative would be to have `B` launch `C` using `startActivityForResult()`. In this case, `C` could return information (either in the `resultCode` or the returned `Intent`) that would allow `B` to determine if it should or should not finish.